# Non-destructive explosion of vector objects

Tags: animation, effects

I have a logo made of little dots, and I'd like to have them 'burst out to space' without losing their individual shape in the process.

I looked up for explosion effects tutorials but I got only the smoky fire kind of explosion, or either fragmentations of solids. So I basically miss the term of the non-destructive bursting effect.

What is it? And in case what tutorial do you suggest?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You could cut the *Gravity* in the *Scene* panel, give *Rigid Body* to your objects, create a *Force Field > Force* at the center, and make it strong enough to make the objects explode:

[image]

Or simply enable the *Options > Only Affect > Locations* and scale to make the objects move away from each other, keyframe the start and end locations.